# How to show one div and hide another div in javascript on same html page

Tags: javascript, html

I am having one html page in which all navigation (lets say them the TABS) resides.

I wrote a javascript to show one  and hide another one on link click.

It works well on the tab i want but when i navigate to another tabs that div is showing on the bottom. I dont want it to display it in all other tabs.

This is my javascript code:

```
function displayBlock(divName){
    if(document.getElementById("vend")) {
        var oldDiv = document.getElementById("vend");
        oldDiv.style.display = 'none';
        //show div
        var newDiv = document.getElementById(divName);
        newDiv.style.display = 'block';

    }
    else{
        var newDiv = document.getElementById(divName);
        newDiv.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

How to modify it to meet the need?

HTML Structure:

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane" id="dashboard">
     <div class="container">
         <!-- Container code -->
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="vend">
     <div class="container">
         <!-- Container code -->
          <a id="auto-topup2" href="dashboard#auto-topup" onclick="displayBlock('schedule');">
               Schedule Autovend                          
          </a>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="commision">
     <div class="container">
         <!-- Container code -->
     </div>
  </div>
  <div id="schedule" style="display:none">
      <div class="tab-pane" id="auto-topup">
        <div class="container">
           <!-- Container code -->
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

In the vend section i have created a whose onclick will call the function and hide the Div with vend id and show Div with schedule ID....But the DIV with scehdule ID is showing in all the tabs..

I hope now it can be somewhat undestandable

Comment: Better work with classes. Give all tabContent the same class, eg content. When a special content should be displayed hide all elements with the class and just show the selected one.

Comment: Why are you putting the selector `document.getElementById("vend")` in an if statement? There's no condition to meet?

Comment: i just gave it a try....i know its worth nothing

Comment: Can you put your code in a fiddle for us to look at please?

Comment: You should create a snippet on jsfiddle or stack snippet to show what you want to achieve and tell us why the code is not act as you expect, in your current code, its not easy to guess what's the result you expect.

Comment: @mimo i dont want to hide all the divs'....i just want to hide the one in similar tab

Comment: if you culd give us some html we can try to understand your structure.

Comment: Added the HTML structure

Answer (score 0):

To hide all tabs without the selected one you can use this function:

```
function displayBlock(idOfBlock) {
    document.getElementByClass('block').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(idOfBlock).style.display = 'block'
}

<div class="block" id="hello">
    hello
</div>
<div class="block" id="foobar">
    foobar
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that hide the desired tab for a fraction of a second? I guess that you could remove the class from `idOfBlock`and then add it again but I don't like that solution either

Comment: it would, but the user wont recognize it. It is the smallest solution. If you don't want to hide it you have so safe it in a global variable but I don't like this way.